# Sqlite - Xamarin application changes model - cannot retrieve configuration info from database

Tags: c#, sqlite, xamarin

I have an Android app with a sqlite database. I stored the configuration info in a table `Configuration`. That object has changed and I have the app installed on many devices. I want to query the table to obtain a key that I used to get a security token + the device configuration from an API. The model changed, now it has a new string property. When I select the table it always returns null. I suppose it's because this model change.

This always returns null:

```
public async Configuration ConfigurationGet()
{    
    var lst =  await database.QueryAsync<Configuration>("SELECT * FROM [Configuration]")

    if (lst != null && lst.Count() > 0)   
        return lst.First();
    else
        retrun null;
}
```

I tried:

```
var lst = await dbCon.QueryAsync<Object>("Select key from [Configuration]", null)
```

but it doesn't work ...

Ideas?

Comment: Did you mistype "configuracion"?

Comment: Nono i translated it 4 you

Comment: "var lst =  await database.QueryAsync<Configuracion>("SELECT * FROM [Configuration]")" should be "var lst =  await database.QueryAsync<Configuration>("SELECT * FROM [Configuration]")"   ?

Comment: No. The Configuration Object changed, i need to query one column only without the Configuration type as result